# Animate a StackPanel when the property Visibility changes

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

In WPF 3.5 (with SP1), I have simply **StackPanel that I would like to animate when I change the property Visibility**. I have no idea of the height of this StackPanel since its content determines its height. So when I change the property of my StackPanel to Visible (progressPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;) I would like to see an animation (probably an DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames from 0 to X).

Moreover, I have multiple StackPanel that I would like to see with this behavior (so in the best case, I need something generic). **Does anybody have an idea on how to do that?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create and reuse custom StackPanel style that triggers animation when Visibility changes:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation .../>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: You answered very well part of my question. The second part is how the Height of the StackPanel. Considering that I don't know the height, how do I use the DoubleAnimation?

<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" From="0" To="--???--" Duration="00:00:00.5" />

Comment: It's not clear what kind of effect you want to achieve. Please update you're question and provided detailed info on desired StackPanel's behavior. Manually changing StackPanel.Height property doesn't look like a good idea to me

Answer (score 2):

If you need an expanding kind of effect with an animation which grows vertically. Do a double animation on the ScaleTransform.ScaleY property of the panel from 0 to 1 if it is a vertical oriented panel.

Comment: Why a negative for me :).  When you can't determine the actual height of the stackPanel it is better to animate the ScaleTransform.ScaleX from 0 to 1 which will do the trick, try it out and then vote down.