# How to animate visibility of a StackPanel in Silverlight to expand and collapse?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, animation, silverlight-4.0

In my case, I would like the expand/collapse to happen from left to right and right to left respectively.

The animation should happen when the visibility changes.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432550/animate-a-stackpanel-when-the-property-visibility-changes

Answer (score 1):

You could create two animation storyboards (One for expanding and one for Collapsing) that animates the Width of the stackpanel, then on StackPanel_VisibilityChanged run the appropriate animation.

Comment: Do you have an example that animates the current width of the StackPanel? All the examples I see are based on fixed widths.

Comment: I remember doing something like this a while back although I ended up getting rid of it and animating my window differently so I don't have the code on me (switched to a ScaleAnimation which went from 0 to 100%). I think I had the storyboard's DoubleAnimation "From" bound to StackPanel.RenderWidth and "To" set to 0. Animation existed in the Resources, not in a style, and it was ran by calling Storyboard animation = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("StoryboardName"); animation.Begin(); from the code behind.

Comment: If that doesn't work try animating RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX). That's what I'm currently using. I think if you don't set a CenterPoint it'll animate in place so the effect will be the same as expanding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend animating on the Width property rather than ScaleX.
Otherwise the entire control (StackPanel) will look crunched/stretched as its animating.